# How to call a controller outside of an area?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my application I have an area "Member". 
Outside this member area I have a folder named "Generic" which is having a controller "DataBindController". 
This controller will be used in all areas. So to keep it common, i am keeping it in a separate folder outside of areas.
My route config is as follows:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        var ObjRoute = routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults:new {controller = "Login", action = "MemberLogin", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
            namespaces: new string[] { "MyApp.Generic.*" }).
            DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "Member"});
        //ObjRoute.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
    }
}
```

Here's the project directory structure.
[image: Project directory structure]

The Test controller inside Generic folder is as follows:

```
namespace MyApp.Generic
{
    public class DataBindController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return Content("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting following error when I call the test controller using "http://localhost/MyApp/Generic/DataBind/Test"

> Error in Path :/MyApp/Generic/DataBind/Test The controller for path
>   '/MyApp/Generic/DataBind/Test' was not found or does    not implement
>   IController.

Please give me some idea on this issue.

Comment: `/DataBind/Test`. Directories have no bearing on routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your address doesn't match your defined route. `Generic` is just a folder. `MVC` doesn't care about the folder your controller is in.

the correct one should be like this :

http://localhost/MyApp/DataBind/Test

so the `DataBind` will be the `controller` and `Test` the `Action`.

**Update:**

your route is

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

When you have **Generic** in your address, `Asp.net` matchs parts this way : Generic is the `Controller`, DataBind is `Action` and Test is the `Id`. of course it can't find such a thing. But when you remove `Generic` , every part goes to its real place.

To have `Generic` in the address, you should change your route to this:

```
Generic/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

To read more about routing :

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: Yes! It works, but can you explain how it works when I remove the folder(namespace) name from url